# python create netCDF with attributes

Tags: python, xml, netcdf

I have a XML file which I want to serve as the base for a netCDF file. I am ok with reading the XML file and creating the netCDF file, both in python.

Each group or variable in the XML file has attributes and I want to add them to the netCDF file. My problem is that I do not know the names of the attributes and this whole thing needs to be automatic.

The usual way of creating and adding an attribute in python for netCDF would be like this:

```
grp.attr = 'name'
```

I now need to do this automatic, I do not know what 'attr' really is. If I use 'attr' as a variable name, 'attr' will be added to the netCDF file and not the actual name.

I will try and illustrate this. Lets say I have three attributes for my group called:

```
<attribute name="alphabet" value="abc"/>
<attribute name="number" value="42"/>
<attribute name="version" value="ncc1701"/>
```

I want these attributes to be in the file, but at time of writing I have no insight where which attribute will be, what its name is etc. So I loop over all attributes and would write a code similar to this:

```
for att in list_attributes:
  attr_name = att.name
  attr_value = att.value
  grp.attr_name = attr_value
```

If I do this I will end up with **one** attribute in my netCDF file with the name 'attr_name' and the value 'ncc1701' instead of the intended three attributes.

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use netCDF4 package ?

Comment: @C.Dlp, yes I use the netCDF4 package for python.

Comment: If you create a new netCDF variable for each attribute in your loop, normally it will work

Comment: @C.Dlp could you perhaps explain that in a bit more detail? Do you mean to create a variable instead of an attribute? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can implement something like that :  

for att in list_att:  
evar = ncfile.createVariable(name, vtype, dim, fill_value=_FillValue)  
evar[:] = att.value

Comment: @C.Dlp thanks for this. It works, but I do end up with variables not with attributes, so I somehow get the information into the netCDF file, but not as it is needed.

Comment: Did you try with `setncattr` method ?

Comment: @C.Dlp `setncattr` did the trick :) Do you want to post this as an answer, then I can accept this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setncattr` method from netCDF4 package in the loop.

Comment: maybe there's a downvote because one could enhance on how to use the `setncattr` method of Dataset/Group/Variable instances of the netCDF4 package. It is analogous to Python's `setattr`, plus there's also the possibility to create many attributes using `setncatts`